# Remove the entire row if its cell contains "no" text

Tags: xml, xslt

If cell contains value "no" remove the entire row using xslt.
The Workbook xml code given below:

```
<Table ss:ExpandedColumnCount="4" ss:ExpandedRowCount="4" x:FullColumns="1"
 x:FullRows="1">
<Row>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s23"><Data ss:Type="String">Name</Data></Cell>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s24"><Data ss:Type="String">Section</Data></Cell>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s24"><Data ss:Type="String">Aggregate</Data></Cell>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s25"><Data ss:Type="String">Result</Data></Cell>
</Row>
<Row>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s26"><Data ss:Type="String">AA</Data></Cell>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s27"><Data ss:Type="String">A</Data></Cell>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s27"><Data ss:Type="Number">68.0</Data></Cell>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s28"/>
</Row>
<Row>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s26"><Data ss:Type="String">BB</Data></Cell>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s27"><Data ss:Type="String">A</Data></Cell>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s27"><Data ss:Type="Number">99.0</Data></Cell>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s28"/>
</Row>
<Row ss:Height="14.0">
<Cell ss:StyleID="s29"><Data ss:Type="String">CC</Data></Cell>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s30"><Data ss:Type="String">C</Data></Cell>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s30"><Data ss:Type="Number">20.0</Data></Cell>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s31"><Data ss:Type="String">no</Data></Cell>
</Row>
</Table>
```

In the above coding, fourth row fourth cell contains "no" text. Need to remove that entire row using xslt.

Answer (score 2):

Hope the below code works.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" exclude-result-prefixes="ss"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="node() | @*" mode="#all">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* |node()" mode="#current"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="attribute[@name = 'String']/text()">
      <xsl:value-of select="replace(., '^.*no.*$\n*', '', 'm')"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: NachuArun -  Ennama ippadi panrengalema